# var vs let in for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block. but still dont understand why below given code is output so differently.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 1000)
}
```

//0,1,2,3,4

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 1000)
}
```

//5,5,5,5,5

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let Read the description

Comment: Upvoting. Even though this is a duplicate, and the OP should have searched a bit more, I find this question title, question body, and tymeJV's answer clearer for than in the dupe.

Answer (score 5):

The second outputs like so because the time your `timeout` actually runs, `i` is set to the last iteration. Why? Because if you use `var` in your `for` the variable is hoisted outside the loop scope, so it actually looks like:

```
var i = 0;
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    //and when your timeout runs, i is 5
}
console.log(i); //5
```

And `let` doesn't hoist outside:

```
for (let i=0;i<5;i++){

}
console.log(i); //undefined, not hoisted
```

Comment: and let is the oposite.

Comment: Brilliant! So, while the timeout is still running the var `i` is incrementing its value, right? That same function without the timeout would result in the same output in both cases (with let & with var), right?

Comment: @SrAxi that's correct

Comment: The final value of `i` is 5, not 4. The final-expression (`i++`) is evaluated at the end of the loop iteration, before the next evaluation of the condition (`i<5`) .

Comment: @GerardoFurtado -- Woops, thanks for that, made the edit! (And I actually didnt realize that final expression was eval'd... learn something new all the time)